# Why first hop of traceroute is not the default router?

Tags: linux, networking, router, linux-networking, route

default route is:

`ip route show`:

```
10.0.0.0/23 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.150
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100
```

And

`traceroute www.google.com`

```
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.25.68), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.2.246 (10.1.2.246)  0.201 ms  0.184 ms  0.166 ms
 2  218.66.X.X (218.66.X.X)  1.657 ms  1.667 ms  2.210 ms
```

What does this mean?

Since the default route is `10.1.1.1`, so the first record of `traceroute` should be `10.1.1.1`, right?

Why it is instead `10.1.2.246`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `10.1.1.1` cannot be the first hop because it is not in the same network as the interface. The gateway for the network interface must be the first hop. The gateway is where the host will send any traffic destined to a different network, and it is a hop.

Comment: How to find out the gateway info from a linux host?

Comment: The command is `ip route show`, just the one you used in your initial question.